# Implementing ls -la in C

Tags: c, linux

i have 3(that i know of) problems with this:

1. i aint getting the right restrictions (fixed
2. it wont color my symbolic links-i want to color for example my symbolic links in magenta but i i cant seem to make it work
3. the dir\file\link isnt working properly(fixed)

[heres my output](http://s4.postimg.org/4mpjil15p/a_out.jpg)

[and heres the output from the inbuilt command](http://s30.postimg.org/fcuu2se5t/ls_la.jpg)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/dir.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define KNRM  "\x1B[0m"
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

static char perms_buff[30];

const char *get_perms(mode_t mode)
{
  char ftype = '?';

  if (S_ISREG(mode)) ftype = '-';
  if (S_ISLNK(mode)) ftype = 'l';
  if (S_ISDIR(mode)) ftype = 'd';
  if (S_ISBLK(mode)) ftype = 'b';
  if (S_ISCHR(mode)) ftype = 'c';
  if (S_ISFIFO(mode)) ftype = '|';

  sprintf(perms_buff, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c %c%c%c", ftype,
  mode & S_IRUSR ? 'r' : '-',
  mode & S_IWUSR ? 'w' : '-',
  mode & S_IXUSR ? 'x' : '-',
  mode & S_IRGRP ? 'r' : '-',
  mode & S_IWGRP ? 'w' : '-',
  mode & S_IXGRP ? 'x' : '-',
  mode & S_IROTH ? 'r' : '-',
  mode & S_IWOTH ? 'w' : '-',
  mode & S_IXOTH ? 'x' : '-',
  mode & S_ISUID ? 'U' : '-',
  mode & S_ISGID ? 'G' : '-',
  mode & S_ISVTX ? 'S' : '-');

  return (const char *)perms_buff;
}

char pathname[MAXPATHLEN];

void die(char *msg)
{
  perror(msg);
  exit(0);
}

static int
one (const struct dirent *unused)
{
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int count,i;
  struct direct **files;
  struct stat statbuf;
  char datestring[256];
  struct passwd pwent;
  struct passwd *pwentp;
  struct group grp;
  struct group *grpt;
  struct tm time;
  char buf[1024];

  if(!getcwd(pathname, sizeof(pathname)))
    die("Error getting pathnamen");

  count = scandir(pathname, &files, one, alphasort);

  if(count > 0)
  {
    printf("total %dn",count);

    for (i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
      if (stat(files[i]->d_name, &statbuf) == 0)
      {
        /* Print out type, permissions, and number of links. */
        printf("%10.10s", get_perms(statbuf.st_mode));
        printf(" %d", (int)statbuf.st_nlink);
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)){
            printf("%s" KGRN "%s RESET \n",
        files[i-1]->d_name,datestring);                 
        }



        if (S_ISLNK(statbuf.st_mode)){
            printf("%s" KMAG "%s RESET \n",
        files[i-1]->d_name,datestring);                 
        }
    else
          printf(" %s %s\n", datestring, files[i]->d_name);
      }

      free (files[i]);
    }

    free(files);
  }
}
```

m/IenKP.jpg

Comment: Try to be more specific (possibly splitting the question to 3 question - each with a minimal code)

Comment: i managed to fix problem 1 and 3,but im still stuck with 2? can you help me?

Comment: So what's left is an question about ANSI color codes. I would try to compare the output of your program to the output of a program that works (by redirecting to a text file). If this doesn't help, rephrase the question.

Comment: also - write a simple example that just writes a single line in color - it will be easier to read then your full code

Comment: @OphirYoktan i edited the main post as you asked

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example which prints a color:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define KMAG "\033[35m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%smagenta text%s\n", KMAG, RESET);
    return 0;
}
```

Does the above code work for you? If not, there may be something different about your termainal/shell settings pertaining to color.

One issue is here, which is some rather strange C string literal concatenation:

```
printf("%s" KMAG "%s RESET \n", "name", "datestring");
```

In this case, your `RESET` macro is not being substituted because it is part of a string literal.

Also, to debug, you might pipe your output to `hd`, which shows a hex dump of whatever you pipe in. (eg, `./a.out | hd`). Then you can examine, byte by byte, what your program is actually outputting so that you can debug.

Comment: Hi, you code is working
and i followd this example from other thread, printf("This is " KRED "red" RESET " and this is " KBLU "blue" RESET "\n");

Comment: The code you posted in this comment is different than your code from above! Specifically the bit about RESET occurring outside of the quotation marks rather than inside.

Comment: i have tried without the IF statement and its working, so i think i have a problem here : if (S_ISLNK(statbuff.st_mode))